# How to get ASCII for non-numeric characters in a given string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I will have my string as follows

```
String S="AB-1233-444";
```

From this i would like to separate AB and would like to find out the ASCII for that 2 alphabets.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use LINQ to take care of that (testing the syntax now):

```
var asciiCodes = S.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c)).Select(c => (int)c);
```

Or if you don't want to use the LINQ-y version:

```
var characterCodes = new List<int>();

foreach(var c in S)
{
    if(char.IsLetter(c))
    {
        characterCodes.Add((int)c);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd use where !char.IsNumber(c), but the linq is a good answer

Comment: @Kell - !char.IsNumber(c) would still return punctuation (the dashes) which the OP specifically said he didn't want. I forgot about char.IsLetter() though which would do exactly what they need.

Comment: I thought he wanted non-numeric characters cos there are 2 additional non-numeric. In this case then I'd use where Char.IsLetter(c)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a character to a codepoint using this: `(int)'a'`.

Answer (score 0):

To seperate (if you know that it's split on - you can use `string.Split`

To get the ASCII representation of 'A' for example, use the following code

```
int asciivalue = (int)'A';
```

So complete example might be

```
Dictionary<char,int> asciilist = new Dictionary<char,int>();
string s = "AB-1233-444";
string[] splitstrings = s.Split('-');
foreach( char c in splitstrings[0]){
  asciilist.Add( c, (int)c );
}
```

Comment: What you mean by asciilist here

Comment: Maybe not a good name, but I have no clue what the OP want with this list, so I just store it somewhere instead of doing any logic to it. It's a dictionary containing a char, and it's associated ascii value, but as you probably understand, it's quite useless except for the example effect itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var result = (from c in S.ToCharArray() where
   ((int)c >= (int)'a' &&
   (int)c <= (int)'z') || 
   ((int)c >= (int)'A' && 
   (int)c <= (int)'Z') select c).ToArray();
```

Non-linq version is as follows:

```
List<char> result = new List<char>();
foreach(char c in S)
{
  if(((int)c >= (int)'a' &&
     (int)c <= (int)'z') || 
     ((int)c >= (int)'A' && 
     (int)c <= (int)'Z'))
      {
        result.Add(c);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Can i have this in non-linq version

Comment: for non linq version look for Updated version:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring to get alphabets alone and use a for loop to store value of alphabets in an array and print it one by one